# Tracking item order for storage to and retrieval from a DB

Tags: database, django, crud

I'm trying to figure out how I'm going to 'CRUD' the order of items I have in a group that I'm storing in a database. (Pseudo statement of: select * items from app where group_id = 1;)

My guess is that I just use an numeric field and just increase/decrease the number as more items are added to/removed from the group.  I can then just update the items number in this field as they are moved around.  However, I've seen this go really badly wrong in an old legacy app where items would get out of sync and you'd have a group where the order ended up something like this:

```
0,1,1,3,4,5
0,1,1,1,4,5
```

This wasn't handled very gracefully by the application either, and broke the application necessitating manual intervention to reorder the items in the DB.

Is there a way to avoid this pitfall?

EDIT: I would also maybe want the items available in multiple groups with multiple orders.
I think in that case I would need a many to many relationship for both the group to item relationship and the item to order relationship. /EDIT

I'll be doing this in the Django framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking; because ordering is one thing, and grouping of related objects is something else entirely.

Databases don't store the order of things, but rather the relationships (grouping) of things.  The order of things is a user interface detail and not something that a database should be used for.

In django, you can create a `ManyToMany` relationship. This essentially creates a "box" where you can add and remove items that are related to a particular model.  Here is the example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

Here an Article can belong to many Publications, and Publications have one or more Articles associated with them:

```
a = Article.create(headline='Hello')
b = Article.create(headline='World')
p = Publication.create(title='My Publication')

p.article_set.add(a)
p.article_set.add(b)
p.save()

# You can also add an article to a publication from the article object:

c = Article.create(headline='The Answer is 42')
c.publications.add(p)
```

To know how many articles belong to a publication:

```
Publication.objects.get(title='My Publication').article_set.count()
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's not clear in my head which is why I'm struggling to get something down in writing.

I want to store the order state so that the user is presented with a specific order of items (not related to date, alphabetical charfield or item id.)  The complicating factor was having the items in multiple groups.

Comment: Say that you had Articles with the headlines `'hello'
'to'
'our'
'friends'` and you wanted to display them in that order, every time.  The ids are 2,4,3,1 respectively and the date added will follow the ids.  You can't order them by id,datetime or alphabetically, but you want your visitors to see that original order when you output `Publication.objects.get(title='My Publication').article_set.all()` Rather than 'friends', 'hello', 'our', 'to'.  In the templates you need something use to order the presentation to end user without having to manually output each item by id in your preferred order.